# Mysql LIKE is not working when there is & in data

Tags: mysql, hibernate

select name from students where name like '%A&M%';

above query is not giving results whose name contains A&M instead it giving whose name as A(any character)M in name

but when i run this select name from students where name like '%A&MOhan%'; it is giving students whose name contains A&Mohan

I am using hibernate createNativeQuery

Comment: "Any character" pattern in LIKE operator syntax is NOT an ampersand. Read the description in Reference Manual.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the input for special characters with a backslash, so for example:

```
select name from students where name like '%A\&M%';
```

Should give you the correct result